# How can I compare different files by creation date and file size?

Tags: bash, database-backups

I want to check the backup files from last 2 days and compare if the
size of current file (today) is greater than another (yesterday) with
different backup file names.

I have 10 Server with MYSQL and everyday create each server an backup from database and send to backup server.

By some server there is more than one database, therefore server
create different backup files in same day and send to backup server. i
need to be sure if a backup was made today and if the file (today) is
larger than old file (yesterday)?

> 55M 25. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW1_20190525.sql.gz
>
> 48M 25. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW2_20190525.sql.gz
>
> 39M 25. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW3_20190525.sql.gz
>
> 35M 25. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW4_20190525.sql.gz
>
> 42M 25. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW5_20190525.sql.gz
>
> 57M 26. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW1_20190526.sql.gz
>
> 51M 26. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW2_20190526.sql.gz
>
> 20K 26. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW3_20190526.sql.gz
>
> 45M 26. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW4_20190526.sql.gz
>
> 48M 26. Mai 03:45 /home/backup/server1/SW5_20190526.sql.gz
>
> i expect to check:
>
> SW1_20190526.sql.gz > SW1_20190525.sql.gz
>
> SW2_20190526.sql.gz > SW2_20190525.sql.gz
>
> SW3_20190526.sql.gz >  SW3_20190525.sql.gz
>
> SW4_20190526.sql.gz > SW4_20190525.sql.gz
>
> SW5_20190526.sql.gz > SW5_20190525.sql.gz
>
> when OK say 0 OK
>
> when not say 1 Error (for example => SW3_20190526.sql.gz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the ~/testing/* to path/to/your/files*
remember to put the *

NOTE: 
This version of the script assumes that you run it on the desired day. For example (date-command and the latest file entry match)

```
# Set directory to loop through
dir=~/testing/*

# Todays date used to grep for today's file
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)

# Yesterday's date used to grep for yesterday's file
yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d')

# Start point to loop through each SW? files
num=1

# Start looping through directory
for file in $dir; do

    # Get today's file by date
    file_td=$(ls SW[$num]* | grep $today)

    # Get yesterday's file by date 
    file_yd=$(ls SW[$num]* | grep $yesterday)

    # Get size of today's file
    size_td=$(stat -c %s $file_td)

    # Get size of yesterday's file
    size_yd=$(stat -c %s $file_yd)

    # Test if file size is equal or greater than
    if (($size_td >= $size_yd)); then
        echo "$file_td is equal or bigger that $file_yd"
    else
        echo "$file_yd is bigger $file_td"
    fi

    # Limit SW? to 5 so its doesn't attempt the script on none existing file
    # You change the 5 to how ever many SW's there are in the directory
    ((num++)) && [[ $num > 5 ]] && exit

done
```

NOTE: 
This version of the script doesn't assume anything and just grabs the last two entries the directory accepted. This simulates "today" and "yesterday" with out needing you to run the script on the last day.

```
# File Directory to loop through
dir=~/testing/*

# Starting point for file names SW1 - SW?
num=1

# Begin looping through directory
for file in $dir; do

    # Set the latest file in directory SW? to today
    file_td=$(ls SW[$num]* | sort -u -r | sed '1q;d')        

    # Set the second latest file in directory SW? to yesterday
    file_yd=$(ls SW[$num]* | sort -u -r | sed '2q;d')

    # Get size of today's file
    size_td=$(stat -c %s $file_td)

    # Get size of yesterday's file
    size_yd=$(stat -c %s $file_yd)

     # Test if file size is equal or greater than
    if (($size_td >= $size_yd)); then
        echo "$file_td is equal or bigger that $file_yd"
    else
        echo "$file_yd is bigger $file_td"
    fi

    # Limit SW? to 5 so its doesn't attempt the script on none existing files
    # You change the 5 to how ever many SW's there are in the directory 
    ((num++)) && [[ $num > 5 ]] && exit

done
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, but as i mentioned pathway is same  for all files, let i explain it more: today i will have 5 different backup file: SW1_20190528.sql.gz,SW2_20190528.sql.gz,SW3_20190528.sql.gz,SW4_20190528.sql.gz,SW5_20190528.sql.gz and exactly as yesterday :SW1_20190527.sql.gz,SW2_20190527.sql.gz,SW3_20190527.sql.gz,SW4_20190527.sql.gz,SW5_20190527.sql.gz, after 10 days i will have 10 backup files from sw1 and 10 backup files from sw2 etc... . How can i find just last created files from last 2 days for example SW1_20190527 and SW1_20190528 and compair their size with each other?

Comment: @user11563595 ive edited my answer to reflect your comment. i believe this will do it. let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: thanks a lot. it was perfect, i've just another question, what should i do, if i've file1 (10 different backupnames from today,e.g SW1-ABCD_20190528.sql.gz,SW1-FOP_20190528.sql.gz .etc) and file2 with 10 files same but just different daytime(yesterday.e.g,SW1-ABCD_20190527.sql.gz,SW1-FOP_20190527.sql.gz.etc )?

Comment: @user11563595 That should work if it doesn't we will try again. Let me know if that works first.

Comment: @user11563595 your condition "if [ "$file1" -ge "$file2" ]; then" should be written like this "if [ "$file1" -nt "$file2" ]; then"

Comment: no it doen't help, i have always "2" which means error and it's not true :-(

Comment: what im saying is you dont need a variable to test file sizes.  [[ $file1 -nt $file2 ]] && echo "its bigger" or [[ ~/mypath/to/file1 -nt ~/mypath/to/file2 ]] && echo "file1 is bigger" || echo "file2 is bigger"

Comment: could you please change your code with the new variables (today,yesterday) and your last comment ? i'm confusing some now.

Comment: @user11563595 i updated the code for you the code for you with two versions please read the carefully. Also please mark the question answered if this works for you.